# Why do I need secret on delegated az ad app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

what can go wrong if we don’t have secrets/cert on Azure Ad app registration with only delegated permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You only need a secret/certificate if you need to prove your app's identity when acquiring tokens.

If you have a desktop app, mobile app, or other kind of "public client" that runs on a user's device, these cannot prove their identity as they cannot keep a secret.
So for these you would never register a secret/certificate.

If you have e.g. a Web API that is a "confidential client", you only need a secret/certificate if that API needs to call other APIs.
Otherwise those don't need it.
A "traditional" back-end Web app would usually need a secret/certificate to do authorization code flow to authenticate the user.

So it really depends on the type of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do.

### authorized access between resources

- Do use service principal with certificate if you want to access one cloud resource from another: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

> Access to resources is restricted by the roles assigned to the service principal, giving you control over which resources can be accessed and at which level. For security reasons, it's always recommended to use service principals with automated tools rather than allowing them to log in with a user identity.

Most notably, the service principal, can't be used with credential theft using social engineering and much more.

### delegated permissions

That's the way to go if we're talking about user interaction with services that call one another.